# How to use web api to return a collection (array) of arrays of unlabeled values

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I transform a linq select statement in a web api controller to return a collection of arrays of unlabeled values.

E.g.,

```
_db.view.select(_ => new { _.Field1, _.Field2, ... , _.FieldN })
```

returns json in the form:

```
[ { Field1: F1Value1, ... FieldN: FnValue1 },
  { Field1: F1Value2, ... FieldN: FnValue2 } ]
```

I would like to remove the labels from the response:

```
[ [ F1Value1, ... , FnValue1 ],
  [ F1Value2, ... , FnValue2 ] ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hard coding the fields you want anyway, then just hard code them into an array right in the lambda expression:

```
_db.view.select(_ => new string[]{_.Field1, _.Field2, ... , _.FieldN})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I could do an array of dynamic.  The fields are of several different types.

Comment: I found that I had to use a List<dynamic> or List<object> rather than an Object array.  But I don't recall what the error was off hand.